# Drupal View of Users with Link to Particular Content Type

Tags: drupal, view

I am trying to create a View in Drupal that lists all the members of the site.  Easy enough, but I want to have a link for those who create portfolios on the site next to the name.  So I have created a Relationship of User: Content authored.  The problem is that it creates an entry in that list for every piece of content that user has created.  I want it to only show a link if they have created a content type of Portfolio.  But if I try and do any restrictions of that content type it takes off the users that have not created a Portfolio which is not what I want.

So any thoughts on how to make it list every user, even if they have not created a Portfolio yet, and only show a link to their Portfolio if they have with out it showing all the other content they have created?

Any help, links to tutorials, etc would be helpful.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This should work..

1. Change the field setting in the view so the content authored field
   is output as one row
2. Rewrite the output of the content authored field in View, so that that field does not output all items, only output a link. Set it to show nothing when the field is empty.